# Draw a line with specified coordinate and clean canvas

Tags: android

I need to draw a line on a layout, for that I read some question here and I use DrawView class, but I need to clean this view at some point, and draw another line on it (or just change the first line's coordinates if possible).

But I don't know how I could do that easily unfortunately the only idea I have is removing the DrawView from the layout and creating another DrawView everytime.

Edit: I tried to use save(); to save the empty canvas, and restore() everytime I need to clean it, but it doesn't seems to work ...

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    float startX;
    float startY;
    float endX;
    float endY;

    public DrawView(Context context, float startX, float startY, float endX, float endY) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        this.setMinimumHeight(300);
        this.setMinimumWidth(300);

        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        this.endX = endX;
        this.endY = endY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, paint);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
canvas.drawColor(int color)
```

to color your canvas in any color (meaning you clean up all that was drawn before). If you use

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

this should result in cleaning your canvas.

Answer (score -1):

you know, if you want to directly draw on the screen programatically, then you can leave out the XML and do it via SurfaceView, here is a tuttorial : www.edu4java.com/